# Indefinite Integrals Using Natural log

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Hi can someone please help?

I need to evaluate this indefinite integral:

$$\int \frac{(\ln x)^5}x dx$$

I know I need to use substitution, so if I let *u= x* but I can't figure out the antiderivative for the top portion.

Thank you!

Comment: Try $u:=\ln x$. Then $du=\frac{1}{x}dx$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\ln x=t\implies \frac{1}{x}\ dx=dt$
$$\int \frac{(\ln x)^5}{x}\ dx=\int t^5\ dt$$$$=\frac{t^6}{6}+C$$
substituting $t=\ln x$, 
$$=\frac{(\ln x)^6}{6}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=\ln x$ and you get...

$$\int u^5 du$$

$$=u^6/6+C$$
$$=\frac{(\ln x)^6}{6}+C$$